# I want to get the value of data-id and data-test using jquery from span element created dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am not getting the data-id value from the span element on click.

```js
function getvalue() {
  alert($(this).data('id'));
  alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
  alert($(this).data('test'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myclass" data-id="bcd" data-test="sjd" onclick="getvalue(this)">click here</span>
```

to get the data from data-id and data-test on span element click One more thing i have created them dynamically so i cant make a click using #id .Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using an `on*` event attribute so `this` in the function is the `window`, not the element which raised the event. You're passing the element as an argument to the function, so you just need to define the argument within the function signature, like this:

```js
function getvalue(el) {
  console.log($(el).data('id'));
  console.log($(el).attr('data-id'));
  console.log($(el).data('test'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myclass" data-id="bcd" data-test="sjd" onclick="getvalue(this)">click here</span>
```

That being said, you should not be using event attributes as they are very outdated and considered bad practice as a result. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

Your question also states that the elements are dynamically appended, so you'll need to use a delegated event handler in that case. As such you can use `on()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.myclass', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
    console.log($(this).data('test'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myclass" data-id="bcd" data-test="sjd">click here</span>
```

Also, note the use of `console.log()` for debugging instead of `alert()`. The latter should be avoided as it coerces data types, which can hide issues, and it's also modal, which is annoying.

Comment: Thanks it works @Rory McCrossan ,so using "this" was sending the whole window to my function ? Can you please explain what 'el' actually did in getvalue(el) ?

Comment: You send `this` to the function in the call to `getvalue`. `el` is the argument definition in the function itself. I'd suggest reading some JS tutorials on how functions work, eg: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-functions-101-f29c8e7c7f07

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan , yeah i used console.log before i had also seen the whole window passing to "this" but i missed it . :) Thanks a lot you saved my time.

Comment: Also note that the window isn't 'passed' to the function as such, but the function runs under the scope of that object.

Comment: Got it Thanks. @Rory McCrossan